# What is the difference between target and currenttarget in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, event-handling, event-delegation

Can any one please tell me the difference between target and currenttarget in flex?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sure, I've had some trouble with this too.  The `currentTarget` property is the IEventListener you registered the event handler for.  The `target` is the one that dispatched the event that you are currently handling.  So the `currentTarget` changes, the `target` doesn't.

Check out the following example:

**Sample App**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    creationComplete="addListeners()">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            protected function addListeners():void
            {
                greatGrandParent.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
                grandParent.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
                aParent.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
                child.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
                // dispatch event that "bubbles", second param is "true"
                // dispatched from child
                child.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE, true));
            }

            protected function completeHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                trace("target: ", event.target + ", currentTarget: ", event.currentTarget);
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Panel id="greatGrandParent">
        <mx:Panel id="grandParent">
            <mx:Panel id="aParent">
                <mx:Button id="child"/>
            </mx:Panel>
        </mx:Panel>
    </mx:Panel>

</mx:Application>
```

**Output**

```
target:  MyApp.greatGrandParent.grandParent.aParent.child, currentTarget:  MyApp.greatGrandParent.grandParent.aParent.child
target:  MyApp.greatGrandParent.grandParent.aParent.child, currentTarget:  MyApp.greatGrandParent.grandParent.aParent
target:  MyApp.greatGrandParent.grandParent.aParent.child, currentTarget:  MyApp.greatGrandParent.grandParent
target:  MyApp.greatGrandParent.grandParent.aParent.child, currentTarget:  MyApp.greatGrandParent
```

It's a simple tree of display objects, and when the app is ready I:

1. Add listeners for the same event on each component in the tree.
2. Dispatch an arbitrary event (just for demonstration).  I chose `Event.COMPLETE`.

Since everything has registered an eventHandler for that same event, and since I have set `bubbles` to true (`new Event(type, bubbles)`), anything in the tree, from child to greatGrandParent and beyond, that has registered an event handler for `Event.COMPLETE`, will run that method: `completeHandler`.  Events travel up the chain then back down.  The `target` is the one that dispatched the event, so since `child` dispatched it, it should be constant.  The `currentTarget` is what changes.

This means that, say you want to check when you are rolling over a DataGrid in Flex, you want to know when you roll over a Checkbox inside one of the itemRenderers in the DataGrid.  One way is to addEventListener on every itemRenderer's checkbox for `MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER`.  Another way is to addEventListener to the DataGrid itself for `MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER`, and check what the *target* is on the event:

```
protected function dataGrid_rollOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // event.currentTarget is DataGrid
    if (event.target is CheckBox)
        trace("rolled over checkbox!");
}
```

That's how I often use `event.target`.

Hope that helps,
Lance

Answer (score 1):

Thus could help :

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_08.html#219548

Answer (score -9):

You should go through tutorials on this site: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining/ for an introduction to Flex before asking a question like this.  Your question is covered on day 1.