# Trigger event from child to parent in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, flash-cs5

I have a MovieClip with a `MouseEvent` function associated to `CLICK` event. Inside of this MovieClip I have a TextField.

So, when I click on my MovieClip, the handler works fine. Now I need the same behaviour when I click on this TextField, but without change my handler function. I mean, I don't want to change `e.target` to `e.target.parent` if user clicked on TextField instead of MovieClip.

How can I do this?

Some of my source code:

```
public function Main(){
   var m = new menu();
   menuMng.addChild(m);
   m.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openMenu);
}

private function openMenu(e:MouseEvent):void{
   // Do some stuff
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fairly common question - you can use the `event.currentTarget` property instead of `event.target` to reference the object to which you added the event listener.

For a more detailed answer check out this question (don't worry about the Flex aspect of it - this relates to standard Actionscript 3 behaviour):
[What is the difference between target and currenttarget in flex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334050/what-is-the-difference-between-target-and-currenttarget-in-flex)

Answer (score 1):

You can fix problem setting `mouseChildren` property to false on MovieClip m. In this case click on textfield will trigger MouseEvent like if user click on m.
For clarity:

```
var m = new menu();
m.mouseChildren = false;
...
```

I hope this will be usefull to you!

Comment: Thanks! Previous answer help me a lot, but I found this usefull too, so I up vote it :)