# Get click coordinate from the listener in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm currently programing a little flash game and I've encountered some kind of a problem:

I have a sprite, let's call it gameBoard, which contains a background image and a lot of other small sprites. My problem is when gameboard put a click listener on itself, if I happened to click on one of the numerous sprites contained in the gameboard, the localX and localY are the one of the small sprite.

So, my question is:

How can I get the coordinate of my click relative to the event listener?

Comment: Apologies, I didn't read the question correctly. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is what you're asking.

[Trigger event from child to parent in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953314/trigger-event-from-child-to-parent-in-as3)

> This is a fairly common question - you can use the event.currentTarget
>   property instead of event.target to reference the object to which you
>   added the event listener.

To trigger the mouse event for the gameboard only:

```
[gameboard_instance_name].mouseChildren = false;
//[gameboard_instance_name].addEventListener(...);
```

Comment: yes... but no. I need to access the mouse's relative coordiantes on my gameboard, not the object itself (unless there is an other "localX" and "localY" on the currentTarget but i havn't seen any ...)

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. Now you can access the gameboard, but the mouse position in the event still refers to the child. @user1459015 see edit.

Answer (score 0):

So somewhere you've attached your click handler:

```
gameboard.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler );
```

Then in your handler you can do the following:

```
function clickHandler( event:MouseEvent ):void
{
    // First way use stage point and convert to gameboard
    var stagePoint:Point = new Point( event.stageX, event.stageY );
    var gameboardPoint:Point = gameboard.globalToLocal( stagePoint );

    // Second way, use the mouse position on the gameboard 
    // making sure that you only use this handler with the above listener 
    event.currentTarget.mouseX;
    event.currentTarget.mouseY;
}
```